# Processing Vs Memory Optimization

Tags: unity, optimization

I'm creating a game with a lot of elements. Should I store all components that I'll eventually access on class variables (memory) or should I access them when running the script(processor)?

Example:

```
private SpriteRenderer sprite;

void Start () {
   sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

public void StartMovement()
{
    sprite.doSomething();
}
```

VS

```
void Start () {

}

public void StartMovement()
{
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should store them. Storing a reference takes up only 4 or 8 bytes (32bit vs 64bit) space in memory while fetching them using `GetComponent()` can use a lot more, while also it will be a lot slower to execute.

Premature optimization (which you seem to be doing) is a bad thing. You should worry about memory consumption and performance, but not before it becomes a problem. If something is known to be slow (like using `GetComponent()` inside the `Update()` function), you should design your code around that fact. Make the game first, and only after you profile it if it uses too much memory you should start optimizing.